# NetBeans: Spring boot with Swing Application

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-boot, executable-jar

I have spring boot maven project with Swing UI, now I want to build executable jar from it. I am using Netbeans tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works for me in Netbeans.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>TestApp</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven as you mentioned, you can run a `mvn install` goal and in the target directory of your project you will have generated jar file.

That you can run with command:

```
java -jar your-app-name.jar
```